# vim dot command act result not same as full type command with <C-r>"

Tags: vimrc

In the vimgolf challenge [Words in parens](http://vimgolf.com/challenges/5192f96ad8df110002000002), I use `cw(ctrl-r")Esc` to format "one" and then use `w.` to format the next two words, but the results are three copies of the text "(one)".

I use the `:reg` command to confirm the `"` unnamed register content equals "three", and I found another solution that formats the text correctly: use `cw(ctrl-r ctrl-o")Esc` to format "one", then use `w.` to format the next two.

But I'm still confused about the vim dot command in this case: why does the dot command not act the same as typing out the command again? There must be something I have missed about the vim dot command: I hope someone can give me an explanation about this case.

Comment: Have you read the help at [`:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-O)? I think it explains the difference pretty well

Comment: In this case I think one should read `:help i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O`. I think this is a good question, because based on the content, I would think `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R` should work similar to `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O`, but it does not. It is not easy to understand why. Based on the docs, it seems the only difference is autoindent. But only `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O` works as expected with the dot repeat.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt  I already read this in vim before，<C-r>" is insert  last delete or yank text, so 'w.' should same as 'wcw(<C-r>")Esc', then the last delete text became "two", so the 'w.' act result should "(two)" not "(one)", I don't know why

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I confirm not set 'textwidth', 'formatoptions', or 'autoindent' in vimrc

Comment: @9-bits if you could create a reproducible example that would certainly help :)

Comment: There's some discussion about the difference between `CTRL-R` and `CTRL-R CTRL-O` in [the comments to my answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21113/vimscript-surround-word-under-cursor-with-quotes/21119#comment37020_21119).

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL-R "` insert text "one" (in default register) and `.` command just repeat insert the text *one*.
`CRL-R CTRL-O "` will insert current text in `"` register.

Maybe [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/ghrgjb/ciw_vs_viwc_and_repetition/) will help too.