# Vimscript - Surround word under cursor with quotes

Tags: vimscript

I'm writing a Vim plugin which will need to surround the word directly under your cursor with a quotes. I have tried using simple solutions which use commands like "b" and "e" executed in normal mode, in combination with other cursor position commands, though those felt clunky and non-robust.

I wondered if there was perhaps, a builtin way to surround text, or a more expedient method of doing so.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As it stands, your question asks for answers for which it is hard to judge the best—words like simplest and fastest can be subjective and solicit answers based on opinion rather than fact and experience. That doesnt work well with the StackExchange mode. Please [edit] your question to clarify your goals and make them objective. [side note: have a look at tpope’s surround.vim on github]

Comment: I don't think this is quite right obe ben kenobe: if a solution requires a long mapping in the vimrc or is a built in feature with 2 or 3 key-presses, then "simple" and "fast" is readily objective. Also opinions are informed by expertise and experience and can be quite useful when elaborated and explained. I think SO has got to correct it's culture of knee-jerk kill questions when certain keywords come up. You could use a bot to do that if that's what you really want, and then you wouldn't need curators.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can surround the word currently under the cursor in quotes with the following normal mode commands:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Replace `iw` with any other Vim motion/text object to surround other things with quotes<sup>*</sup>. Or `""` with any other pair of characters to surround the object with different things.

<sup>* Or use `c` from visual mode to surround text that is hard to describe with a single motion.</sup>

If you want to surround the object with a longer piece of text, such as an HTML `<p>` tag, you can use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> instead of the `P` put command:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

See [`:help i_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) for more details.

Objects smaller than a line can also be surrounded using the [small delete register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote-), and as of Vim 8.2.2189, this is repeatable via the dot command, making it easy to apply the edit quickly in several different places.

So e.g. to go from this:

```
one two three four
```

to this:

```
(one two) (three four)
```

type:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

*Thanks to Christian Brabandt for [letting us know about the fix](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28528/343), and for [implementing it](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2189)!*

However, as dicussed in the comments, if you attempt to use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to surround an object larger than a single line (or prior to v8.2.2189), when you repeat this with the dot command, it will enter the text from the *original* change command. As [@user938271 explains](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21113/vimscript-surround-word-under-cursor-with-quotes/21119#comment37003_21119), you can workaround this by using <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> instead of a plain <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> when inserting the contents of the register.

So to go from:

```
<li>one
<li>two

<li>three
<li>four
```

to:

```
<ul>
<li>one
<li>two
</ul>

<ul>
<li>three
<li>four
</ul>
```

You can type:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: +1 for the second answer using `<C-r>"` (also possible: `<C-r>-`, when you're changing less than a line.) Using that combination allows you to undo the operation with a single `u`. It also allows you to repeat with `.`, though in that case the repeat will insert the *same* text as the first time, which can be useful if you're quoting the same exact word over and over again.

Comment: @filbranden: If you want the dot command to use the last deleted word (and not always the first), during the first edition, you can press `C-r C-o "` or `C-r C-p "` (instead of just `C-r "`) to insert the deleted word back into the buffer.

Comment: @user938271 That is just **AMAZING!!!** So glad I learned about this one today. I'm still reading the docs, trying to understand why this works. But it's so great that it does! Thanks for pointing this out. If you write this as an answer, I'll upvote it for sure, as far as I can tell that's the *best* way to execute this operation!

Comment: @filbranden: Reading the docs, it's unclear to me, too. But I *think* the difference is that `C-r` inserts the text "as if you typed it, but mappings and abbreviations are not used" - meaning that `.` doesn't "remember" the command `C-r "`, just the actual text that it expanded to (because that's what would have happened if you had typed it). But IMHO the docs really ought to call that out, if that's what is meant.

Comment: @Kevin: I don't think that's the relevant line from the help, because it's mentioned at `:h i^r`, and `C-r` doesn't make `.` behave like `C-r C-o`. I think the relevant line is "Does not replace characters!".
If you insert the deleted word `foo` with `C-r "`, you'll see that the output of `:echo @.` is `foo`.
But if you insert it with `C-r C-o "`, the output of `:echo @.` is `^R^O"`. In the dot register, the keys you pressed have not been replaced with the actual inserted characters. I think that's what "Does not replace characters!" refer to.

Comment: I could be wrong though; the help is not very clear.
Also, the dot command works as expected with `C-r C-o` and `C-r C-p`, but only if the deleted text is characterwise; not linewise.

Comment: Sorry, the dot command does behave as expected; what I meant is that you can't use `C-r C-o` to surround a linewise text without breaking the undo sequence: https://i.imgur.com/rFGJXxy.gif
Here, `Up` breaks the undo sequence (even if you prefix it with `C-g U`).

Comment: If you want to quote Bash variables that start with `$` you can use capital `W`, as in `ciW""`Esc`P`, holding down Shift all the way from `W` to `P`.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, a plug-in for surrounding with quotes exists! [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) is what you're looking for.

To surround the current word in double quotes, you can use `ysiw"` once you have the plug-in installed.

`ys` is the command to surround and object (there's also `cs` to replace one delmiter with another, `ds` to remove surrounding), then [`iw`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#iw) is a [text-object](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#text-objects) defining what to surround  and finally `"` is what to surround it with.

You might want to read [the docs for vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/v2.1/doc/surround.txt) to see all that it can do. It's really a lot!

Comment: See also [vim-operator-surround](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-operator-surround/) and [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich).

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Vim [8.2.2189](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2189) you can easily surround a single word using the [small delete register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote-) like this:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

The whole operation is repeatable using the `.` command. So if you have a line like this:

```
foo bar foobar
```

With the cursor anywhere on the first word, simply type `ciw'<C-R>-'`. This will put single quotes around to first word. For the next two words type `w.w.` and you'll have successfully put single quotes around all 3 words:

```
'foo' 'bar' 'foobar'
```

Comment: Very nice! A bit of a shortcut over the usual `Ctrl+R Ctrl+O "`. Looking forward to the upgrade.

Comment: @filbranden thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. string to double-quote: `This is my dog`
2. put cursor on `T`
3. `4cw""<ESC>P`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Fortunately, adding a `.` to the end makes it a sentence, so `cis""<esc>P` also works (also `cis"<C-R>""<esc>`)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, if it's a task you have to automate, you can use substitutions and some mapping.

For example:

```
nnoremap <LEADER>' :let col=col('.') <BAR> s/.*\zs\<.\{-}\%#.\{-}\>/'&'/ <BAR> call setpos('.', [0, line('.'), col+1, 0])<CR>
```

This will surround the current world with `''` upon hitting `<LEADER>` `'`

---

To make it neater, you can use a vimscript function:

```
function! SurroundMe()
    let cara = escape(nr2char(getchar()), '/\\^$*.[~')
    let col = col('.')
    exe 's/.*\zs\<.\{-}\%#.\{-}\>/'.cara.'&'.cara.'/'
    call setpos('.', [0, line('.'), col + 1, 0])
endfunction

nnoremap <LEADER>' :call SurroundMe()<CR>
```

This function will actually wait for you to input a character, and surround the current word with that character!

Answer (score 0):

In **NVIM** you can use this function and map `<leader>sw` or `<leader>sW` to use `:lua Surround("w")` and `:lua Surround("W")` respectively.

After pressing `<leader>sw` or `<leader>sW` in insert mode you will be asked for the character you want to surround with.

If you want to surround with characters whose closing character is different from the opening character, just type the opening one

Note that this is easily reproduced in **VIM**.

```lua
function Surround(w_or_W)
    local open_char = vim.fn.input("Surround with: ")
    local closed_char = nil
    if open_char == "(" then closed_char = ")" end
    if open_char == "[" then closed_char = "]" end
    if open_char == "{" then closed_char = "}" end
    if open_char == "<" then closed_char = ">" end
    if open_char == "'" then closed_char = "'" end
    if open_char == '"' then closed_char = '"' end
    if open_char == "`" then closed_char = "`" end
    if open_char == "/" then closed_char = "/" end
    if open_char == "|" then closed_char = "|" end

    if w_or_W == "w" then
        vim.cmd("normal! ciw" .. open_char)
    elseif w_or_W == "W" then
        vim.cmd([[normal! ciW]] .. open_char)
    end
    vim.cmd("normal! p")
    vim.cmd("normal! a" .. closed_char)
    vim.cmd("normal! a")
end

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>sw", ":lua Surround('w')<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>sW", ":lua Surround('W')<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
``
```