# Add or remove single quotes around numbers in yaml files with vim

Tags: regular-expression

I'm editing some large YAML files with neovim, and need to add (and remove, in some cases) single quotes around some values.

For example -

`code: 1234`

needs to be changed to

`code: '1234'`

in other cases,

`account_number: '1234'`

needs to be changed to

`account_number: 1234`

I've tried `:%s` in as many ways I can think of, but can't solve it. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe we already have several duplicates of this question: [Vimscript - Surround word under cursor with quotes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21113/vimscript-surround-word-under-cursor-with-quotes), [optimise surround with quotes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28515) and maybe others too

Answer (score 0):

This does it: `:%s/"\([0-9]\+\)"/\1/g`

Comment: `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: @Steve note that your answer is flagged as low quality because of its length. I would be useful to edit it to add an explanation of your command so that someone who is not familiar with `:s` and regex can better understand what you are doing.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!