# How to wrap my visual selection with brackets using vnoremap?

Tags: visual-mode

Suppose, I want to wrap a single word with braces in normal mode using keyboard map (say `<F5>`), I could add the following mapping

```
:nnoremap <F5> i{<Esc>ea}<Esc>
```

But, now I want to extend this for visual mode, where I can select some text and wrap it with braces the same way. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21113/10604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
vnoremap <F5> c{}<Esc>P
```

- `c` for change
- `{}` to insert the braces
- `<Esc>` to leave insert mode
- `P` to past the text before the closing brace

Comment: It seemed so natural to me to select some text, and then press either { or } to get it surrounded by curly braces that I just did:
`vnoremap { c{}<EscP` and also `vnoremap } c{}<EscP` 
And I'll do the same for ( [ " '

Answer (score 1):

You could start by improving your normal mode mapping:

```
nnoremap <F5> ciw{<C-r>"}<C-c>
```

where we:

1. "change" the current word (which means "cut it into the unnamed register and enter insert mode") with `ciw`, see `:help c` and `:help text-object`,
2. insert a `{`,
3. insert the content of the unnamed register with `<C-r>"`, see `:help i_ctrl-r`,
4. insert the closing `}`,
5. and finally leave insert mode with `<C-c>`, which has fewer side effects than `<Esc>`.

Pros:

- fewer unnecessary mode changes,
- fewer side effects,
- cursor can be on any character of the word,
- more idiomatic.

Cons:

- none.

From there, it is easy to devise a visual mode mapping by simply removing the `iw` text object:

```
xnoremap <F5> c{<C-r>"}<C-c>
```